# Export Corel in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-draw

I have a site design in `cdr` format.

1. How can I divide the design into pieces in Corel Draw?
2. Can I export `cdr` file in `psd` or other format that is useful in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting a file to Photoshop will prevent you from editing it further in vectors. It is a little obvious but I need to mention it.

#### The process:

**1)** Define what you want as each separated layer in your project.

**2)** Make a new layer for it, and move the respective objects there.

**3)** Export all the project it as CPT. In the dialog box there is a checkbox almost at the bottom: "Keep Layers".

**4)** Open the generated CPT in PhotoPaint and save it as PSD file. Ready!

---

Some notes.

- The most crucial point is that you define correctly the resolution when exporting to CPT. Play with the size and ppi resolution.
- Corel will export only the "printable layers".
- There is a chance you want to prepare also an empty rectangle with no stroke to define a canvas. For example: imagine that you have a text in the center of the page. The resulting CPT file will be only the text. If you define a canvas this way you will have a bigger file with the same proportions as your page, with the text inside.
- Keep in mind that a vector based layer is diferent than a Photoshop layer. You can have multiple objects in each layer on Corel **(A)**, but all of them will be merged into a single Photoshop layer **(B)**. That is why you need to separate them in layers prior of the export. Only the printable layers will be exported **(C)**.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Hear you may Find your Answer :

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20380133/Open-Corel-draw-files-cdr-with-photoshop.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdSP4JooB9s

Hope so above links will help you out

Comment: Hello Ruchit. Please include the important parts of the linked pages *in your answer itself*. That way your answer will still be helpful if the linked pages are broken